# @Font-Face Failing for IE9 & Firefox

Tags: firefox, css, internet-explorer-9, font-face

Took over this job to finish a landing page and am trying to style it with better fonts...I have toiled with this issue for hours now today however, trying all sorts of different markup, directory placement, font generators etc for @font-face and just can't fix the issue.

Works fine in Safari and Chrome but getting no love in IE or Firefox. The only thing I can think of is that the there is another style overriding mine but I looked through all the linked style sheets for any conflicts and can't seem to find them.  I am having to use the !important declaration to make it work in Chrome so maybe there lies the problem??

http://www.myfruityfaces.com/landing-page

Answer (score 1):

From the error console on your site (along with a whole bunch of other problems):

[00:26:17.097] downloadable font: download failed (font-family: "HelveticaRoundedBlack" style:normal weight:normal stretch:normal src index:0): bad URI or cross-site access not allowed
source: http://www.myfruityfaces.com/wp-content/themes/myfruityfaces/helveticaroundedblack.ttf @ http://www.myfruityfaces.com/wp-content/themes/myfruityfaces/landing.css

Compare "www.myfruityfaces.com" to "myfruityfaces.com" for your actual page.

Comment: Thanks! Going through error console now.  Changed the reference and it now works in Firefox but still no results in IE.

Comment: So found that Adobe eot files aren't working for some reason and that's why IE wasn't showing the font.  Found a comparable font and substituted that for IE.  Not the most ideal solution but it works for now!  Thanks guys.